# Hidden column names are missing when exported from jquery datatables using Tabletools

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

```
requestsTable = $('#reportTable').dataTable({

            sDom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            aLengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
            tableTools: {
                sRowSelect: "os",
                sSwfPath: "TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                aButtons: [
                    {
                        sExtends: "collection",
                        sButtonText: "Save",
                        sButtonClass: "save-collection",
                        aButtons: [ 'copy', 'xls' ]
                    },
                    'print'
                ]
            }
        });
        requestsTable.fnSetColumnVis( 22, false );
        requestsTable.fnSetColumnVis( 23, false );
```

when exported i get the data for the columns 22 and 23 but not their column headers...

html part code is :

```
<table id="reportTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%"   cellspacing="0">  
        <thead>  
            <tr style="font-size: smaller;">  
                <th>Request Id</th>  
                <th>Request<br />Type</th>  
                <th>...</th>  
                   ...  
                   ...  
                   so on.....  
             </tr>  
         </thead>  
        <tbody>  
             <tr>  
                <td>105</td>  
                <td>evt</td>  
                  ...  
                  ...  
                  so on......  
             </tr>  
          </tbody>  
    </table>
```

would like to have all data exported along with the hidden columns...

Comment: how your html looks like?
btw can you format you code?

Comment: html part code :
<table id="reportTable">  
  <thead>  
         <tr style="font-size: smaller;">  
              <th>View Claim</th>  
              <th>Request Id</th>  
              <th>Request<br />Type</th>  
                <th>...</th>  
                   ...  
                  so on.....  
             </tr>  
         </thead>  
        <tbody>  
             <tr>  
                <td>105</td>  
                <td>evt</td>  
                  ...  
                  so on......  
             </tr>  
          </tbody>  
    </table>

Comment: table has 32 columns, i'm getting all 32 columns data in exported csv, but not the column names of the hidden columns

Comment: try replacing `aButtons: [ 'copy', 'xls' ]` with 
`aButtons: [{
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            },]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Won't the table exports only visible columns if I make "mcolumns": visible. I want all columns data and header in exported file., even the hidden columns.

Comment: I see. Take out `"mColumns": "visible",`

Comment: i tried, but it din't work.

Answer (score 0):

Define all your columns headers in the table, load all of them in the jquery script but only show columns of your choice using "visible":true/"visible":false.

This will export all columns including the invisible columns with their headers.